# UITabBarController add viewcontroller without tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an iOS application where I need to add a SideMenu and a UITabBarController, SideMenu and UITabBarController there purpose is to let the users navigates between different ViewControllers, I have 3 tab bar items in UITabBarController and in the SideMenu I have 5 items, when the user click on an item in the side menu I have to show the corresponding view controller

Question:
It's possible to add a ViewController without a TabBarItem to the UITabBarController, when the user click on the side menu item, I trigger the UITabBarController to select the corresponding view controller, or its not possible in UITabBarController I need to find another solution, if so please advice which solution is better.

[image]

In the picture above, These are my viewcontrollers but I need to hide the tab bar item for the last view controller and keep the UITabBarViewController behave normally when I programmatically select the last view controller from the side menu

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing the question? I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Would it help if you just don't use TabBar, and instead present a view controller? (I'm not sure when you want the tabbar visible and when it should not show the  tab bar item)

Comment: 1) you can always hide the tabBar on `viewWillAppear` for certain views using `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` OR  2) you can use `present(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: ()-> Void)` which will present a ViewController which will not have a tabBar on the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ViewController of the side menu is different than the TabBar. You can PUSH the view directly in the controller that is selected in the tabbar in that moment.

Comment: Thanks you are right this is the better solution for this kind of scenario